# How to disable is_email() in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

The issue is that I keep recieving false negative from the is_email wordpress function on multiple plugins I have. I've been looking for a while and I cannot seem to find out how to deal with this issue without altering the core files. I would rather not do so because the website owner doesn't want to re-patch after every update.

the troublesome function is :

`is_email ( string $email, bool $deprecated = false )`

My modification to the core would be to make the function look like this (Having valid emails or not isn't a problematic compared to having these "Your email is invalid" messages.):

`function is_email ( string $email, bool $deprecated = false ){
    return $email;
}`

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/is_email/

Comment: What sort of addresses are you getting false negatives for? I'd think the WordPress team would want to fix it.

Comment: @ceejayoz it isn't really clear tbh. it comes off on random emails. I have an outlook and a hotmail that doesn't work while the others with the same domain do. It does seem to trigger more with long emails. I've read somewhere that it might be related to people using the "+" but these adresses don't even work without it. If I change 1 character they do which leads me to believe it's some kind of "spam flag" but I don't see what part of the function would check for that.

Comment: Do those emails *reliably* fail? If so, can you give us an example of one?

Comment: @ceejayoz if it were up to me I would give them out but they aren't my own but those of clients who complained about receiving the messages so I cannot do so, but I've tested them myself and they do fail at every attempt. (Tested on different plugins.)

Comment: You can find the source for the `is_email` check at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_email/. I'd run the emails through each rule individually and see which one they're triggering.

Answer (score -1):

could modify the behavior of the function "is_email()" with some of the functions of PHP. To modify an existing works.

Look at the following documentation in PHP and you will see that it is simple.

I think it might be a trick to your problem created a new function that returns void.

Regards

[override-function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php)
OR
[rename-function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename-function.php)
OR
[runkit-function-redefine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php)

Comment: Rewriting functions with something like Runkit is a great way to get the developer who replaces you to come after you with a sharp weapon.

Comment: the reason why I cannot accept this answer is that it really isn't "Wordpress friendly" whereas what @Alexander O'Mara said in the comments does respect the CMS way to do things, I'll post the solution later today.